# Source for a DPI Aware Helper Class - Is Channel 9 Helper available to download?

Tags: visual-c++, dpi

At 26.52 in to video at [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-184) talking about DPI Awareness they introduce a helper class.  I didn't see a download link to get the helper class.  Is that available somewhere?

Comment: June 2013? That was before the official launch of even Windows 8.1. I suggest you look for more recent material that covers current DPI support upto and including Windows 10 ([pmv2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)).

Comment: there helper has everything needed and lots of cool support.  The only thing I can find now is basic scale which doesn't have all the cool stuff in that class.  They said it would be made available, but I can't find it?